# How do I emphasize a single word in a quote?

Tags: grammaticality

I am working on my son's senior ad for high school and have a question about quoting. When he was little I would say to him "I'm going to get you" with the "I'm" said long for effect. I was told to either make the font bigger or put in italics, but this is not an option for the ad builder site I am using. I am considering using single quotes to highlight this word. does this work and if so do I need to use a period?

> "'I'm' going to get you."

Comment: I have edited your question to present what you are considering. Please edit it to correct this if you are considering something different.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was thinking but was not positive enough to finalize without help. Thanks again! Did I mention this is due tomorrow so your prompt response is much appreciated!

Comment: please keep in mind that the edit and an answer are two different things. The edit is not meant to reinforce the correctness of your suggestion, but instead to properly present it so that answers may follow. If you are satisfied with an answer provided, please mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of quotes, using italics or bold is a good way to emphasize a single word.

> "*I'm* going to get you."
>   "**I'm** going to get you."

Both of which emphasize this as though it's important that you are the one doing the getting. However, if you just want to extend it to match the vocalization, you may be better off throwing out formal usage and going with something more like:

> "IIIIIIIIIIIIII'm gonna get you!"

Comment: Thanks again, thought I would return to your informal version. I spoke with an English professor and he felt that to add the vocalization surrounding the "I" portion of the word "I'm" that I should use something like "I'MMMM. I guess my next question is is their a proper way to write this? Must admit your version seems to highlight it better since the main focus when spoken is the I said for a few seconds again for since he was young.

Comment: Oh and just curious why the rule does not apply here for a single quote after the word "I'm"? From what I gathered it appeared that it worked but you and the professor have offered it differently.  Thanks again.

Comment: The edit that I made to your post to indicate what you meant was not supposed to be an indication that I agreed with the structure. Having single quotes around a contraction is incredibly confusing. 'I'm' does not provide enough distinction between the single quotes and the apostrophe. Do not do this.